# how do i remove empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
['New Zealand',
 'England',
 'Australia',
 'India',
 'South Africa',
 'Pakistan',
 'Bangladesh',
 'West Indies',
 'Sri Lanka',
 'Afghanistan',
 'Netherlands',
 'Ireland',
 'Oman',
 'Scotland',
 'Zimbabwe',
 'Nepal',
 'UAE',
 'United States',
 'Namibia',
 'Papua New Guinea',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 team = soup5.find_all("span",class_='u-hide-phablet')

team_name = []

for i in team:

    team_name.append(i.text)
```

i was webscraping icc top ten team
in this output i want to remove empty list please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if i`:

```
for i in team:
    if i:
        team_name.append(i.text)
```

If that doesn't work use:

```
for i in team:
    if i.text:
        team_name.append(i.text)
```

Comment: @bishwajitbhattacharya Please accept it by clicking the accept mark ✔️ if it works.

Comment: hmmm, wiki? It is dupe.